# More Than 2 Y axis in Grafana

Tags: highcharts, grafana, opentsdb

Is there a way to create more than 2 Y axes in Grafana? I have a use case where I need to display multiple metrics on the same graph and these metrics have different magnitudes. My datasource is OpenTSDB 2.2.0.

[Here's an example using Highcharts.](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)

Thanks!

IWell

Comment: In the Highcharts you can create no-limited array of any axis.

Answer (score 4):

Grafana currently only supports creating a maximum of 2 Y-axes for constructing a graph.

This was answered [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1893).